# Mismatch Between Processor Architecture for Windows Store App & Windows Run Time Component

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to create the store packages for a windows store app that includes a Windows Run Time component for running a background process that updates the Lock Screen. The app runs fine, but when I try to create the store packages I get this error:

There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "AMD64" and the processor architecture of the reference "WindowsRuntimeComponent1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

There seems like there's a dozen of different combinations I can tweak in the configuration manager, and there's very little help online regarding this problem. This is very frustrating - the app runs fine on my own machine, and now when I'm ready to finalize and upload the app I hit this brick wall.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project properties in visual studio. Under Compile, change Target CPU to x86

You get to the project properties by:

1. go the solution explorer
2. right click the phone app project
3. click properties in the context menu
4. On the left hand side, there should be a vertical nav menu, click Compile
5. Change the Target CPU to x86 and save

Comment: Can you walk me through the steps exactly please. Is this for the main project, or the Windows Runtime project? I don't see a 'Compile' option in either properties.  I'm using VS Ultimate 2013.

Comment: I still don't see a Compile menu, but the 'Platform Target' is already set to x86. Not sure why it's saying AMD64...

Comment: Ok got it! But I can only create an x86 bundle. Can't create x64 (AMD64) or ARM files. Is this because of the Windows Run Time component, it's only X86?

Comment: Everything has to match.  If one of the projects can only be built in x86 for some reason, then the entire solution can only be built in x86.  But perhaps you just need to add the x64 and ARM platform options to the project?

Comment: I am not aware of a way to compile .NET/Windows program to ARM (I could be wrong, have not ever tried to build an ARM app).

As far as I know, the .Net framework only exists on x86 and x64(AMD64).

If you want to target ARM phones you need to build a Metro/Modern app